# Delphi Bitmap in Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, bitmap, firemonkey

This is my code that tries not to block the app in Android while loading one or more images.

Every so often freezes or does not load properly.

If anyone knows a way to do what I need would be grateful.

This is my procedure:

```
uses

  System.IOUtils,
  System.Threading,
  System.SyncObjs,

  FMX.Surfaces,

  MyTasks;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  AniIndicator1.Enabled := True;
  AniIndicator1.Visible := True;
  Button1.Enabled := False;

  TTask.Run(

    procedure
    var
      VBitmapSurface: TBitmapSurface;
      VFiles: TStringDynArray;
      VFilesIndexes: TArray<NativeInt>;
      VFile: String;
      VIndex: Integer;
      VBitmapData: TBitmapData;
      VMapped: Boolean;
      VCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
    begin
      VCriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;
      VCriticalSection.Acquire;

      VFiles := SearchFiles( [ TPath.GetPicturesPath, TPath.GetCameraPath, TPath.GetSharedPicturesPath, TPath.GetSharedCameraPath ], [ '*.jpg', '*.jpeg' ] ).Value;
      VFilesIndexes := Randomizer( Length( VFiles ) ).Value;
      VFile := VFiles[ VFilesIndexes[ 0 ] ];

      VBitmapSurface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
      try
        if TBitmapCodecManager.LoadFromFile( VFile, VBitmapSurface ) then
        begin
          VMapped := False;
          TThread.Synchronize( nil,
            procedure
            begin
              Image1.Bitmap.SetSize( VBitmapSurface.Width, VBitmapSurface.Height );
              VMapped := Image1.Bitmap.Map( TMapAccess.Write, VBitmapData );
            end
          );
          if VMapped then
          try
            if VBitmapData.Pitch = VBitmapSurface.Pitch then
              Move( VBitmapSurface.Bits^, VBitmapData.Data^, VBitmapSurface.Pitch * VBitmapData.Height )
            else
              for VIndex := 0 to VBitmapSurface.Height - 1 do
                Move( VBitmapSurface.Scanline[ VIndex ]^, Pointer( NativeInt( VBitmapData.Data ) + VIndex * VBitmapData.Pitch )^, VBitmapData.Width * VBitmapSurface.BytesPerPixel );
          finally
            TThread.Synchronize( nil,
              procedure
              begin
                Image1.Bitmap.Unmap( VBitmapData );
              end
            );
          end;

        end;
      finally
        VBitmapSurface.DisposeOf;
      end;

      VCriticalSection.Release;
      VCriticalSection.DisposeOf;

      TThread.Synchronize( nil,
        procedure
        begin
          AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
          AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
          Button1.Enabled := True;
        end
      );

    end

  );

end;
```

Comment: Yes, you can load a bitmap in a thread. You cannot, however, **display it on your UI** in a thread. It's the visual portion that isn't thread safe. As you haven't provided any code, it's virtually impossible to tell you why you get "crash and empty or black images".

Comment: @KenWhite Apparently the Delphi VCL bitmap is not threadsafe, even if you don't display it. Bizarre really. Third party libraries would appear to be the way to go.

Comment: @David: This is FMX, unless the VCL has been ported to Android. (Fourth paragraph.)

Comment: @Ken Does that make NGLN's answer invalid?

Comment: @user Is it possible that your code has a fault in it?

Comment: @David: I wasn't addressing NGLN's answer; I was responding to your comment to me regarding the **VCL bitmap** not being threadsafe.

Comment: @Ken I know. That was clear. I had moved on.

Comment: @David: Apparently not.

Comment: @Ken Enough. I wasn't arguing with you. You corrected me. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot assign to bitmap of image1 of form1 in a thread, you cannot avoid it. Consequently, I guess, there's not much point loading from a file to another bitmap in a thread, just to assign the image in the main thread.

Comment: It's always difficult to believe what someone says, or get motivated to help, when the code that is posted doesn't match the rest of the question. In this case you claim to be executing this code, and yet it does not compile. Please post real code. What's more please post complete code.

Comment: I worked two hours to produce this procedure that summed up what I need!
I managed to otter good results but is not perfect.
Every now and then the images are not loading properly.

Comment: A procedure that "sums up what you need" should be able to be **compiled**, which means you need have actually written it in the IDE and been able to compile it without error (and so should we). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I posted only the code necessary to run the procedure without errors. it is sufficient to fill it to realize they have to change only one variable. So I do not understand your post.
I also simplified the question with:
1) What does
2) What is wrong
3) request for help

Now I do not understand English well, what's the problem in simple terms?

Comment: Your latest update is much better. Thank you. I wonder why you feel the need to call DisposeOf. What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: Calling `TBitmap.LoadFromFile` inside a thread and assigning it to the real bitmap within the main thread you only have a 50:50 chance to see the image (no exceptions and the thread bitmap is filled with data). Why ... I don't know ... the only chance is to load the file as a stream (thread) and load that stream to the bitmap (main thread).

Comment: Calling DisposeOf in Android I frees the memory used. If I use Free me destroys the object but I do not free the memory.

Comment: Thanks Sir Rufo. 
But your workaround does not solve the problem that the app frezze until it has completed the moving of the image buffer.
I try but same.

Comment: I know what DisposeOf does. But you aren't meant to use it as a rule.

Comment: @user Calling `DisposeOf` under ARC (mobile apps) does not free memory. It calls the detructor code only. Memory is freed when the reference count becomes zero. Calling `Free`, also does not free memory, it only sets the reference to nil, which decrements the ref. count. If the ref.count becomes zero then memory is freed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
So what is a direct way to bring reference count to 0 and then immediately free the memory?

Comment: @user the only thing that can bring reference count to 0 is not having any strong reference to the object. If you have one (last) reference and you set that reference to nil, then count should drop to 0. There is no other way you can force setting reference count to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately FMX bitmaps are not thread safe, you can only use them in the main thread (or in a synchronised portion of another thread).

Comment: Documentation directly states, that FMX bitmaps can be created/used/deleted in any thread:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Multi-Threading_for_TBitmap,_TCanvas,_and_TContext3D
If they don't, then it is either bug in FM framework or in your code. If you provide any example to demonstrate the issue, then we can try to figure out what is wrong. Otherwise your answer seems to be not so useful.

Comment: +andrei galatyn you should look at the dates first, my comment is three years old and a lot has changed since in FMX.

Comment: Three years ago your answer didn't have any details/example too.